# Bash script that count files using wc but making it exit if count does not match as expected

Tags: bash, for-loop, wc

I have the following folder structure:

```
files
├── 0
│   ├── textfile1.txt
│   ├── textfile2.txt
files
├── 1
│   ├── textfile1.txt
│   ├── textfile2.txt
files
├── 2
│   ├── textfile1.txt
│   ├── textfile2.txt
```

and to count the text files in each folder, I came up with a script as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

total=2
for (( i=0; i <= $total; ++i ))
do
    count=$i
    if (( ${#count}  < 2 ))
    then
       count="$count"
    fi

    echo "subfolder: $count"
    ls files/$count/ | wc -l
done
```

When I run this script like "./script.sh", it will go an count the number of files inside each folder and print the following:

> subfolder: 0
>
> 2
>
> subfolder: 1
>
> 2
>
> subfolder: 2
>
> 2

***My question is: How do i modify this script to make it exit with error if a folder contains less than 2 files. If it contains exactly 2, then it is good... if it contains 1 or less, then it should throw error and exit, otherwise it should return that all files are OK and exit with code 0.***

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: `if [ $count -lt 2 ] ;then exit 1;fi`

Comment: [: -lt: unary operator expected @P....

Comment: In the root directory, you have 3 separate directories named "files" -- can't happen.

Comment: your `$count` is empty, you should use it like `if [ ${count:-0} -lt 2 ] ;then exit 1;fi`

Comment: @glennjackman, actually a good spot. :P - I was just testing something with a local script... before i do this in AWS S3, e.g: "aws s3 ls s3://my-bucket/files/ | wc -l"

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```sh
for dir in */; do                   # iterate over the directories
    files=( "$dir"/* )              # array of files in that directory
    if (( ${#files[@]} < 2 )); then
        echo "Error: directory $dir has < 2 files" >&2
        exit 1
    fi
done
```

If your directory hierarchy is more like what you show, then you may want:

```
for dir in */*/; do
```

it depends on your script's current working directory.

Comment: Nice, clean solution. To fully meet the requirements, add a few extra lines: 1) `echo "Subfolder: ${dir}"`.2) Assign the number of items in the file array to a variable. 3) Use the variable in your test. 4) If no error, print the number of files.

Comment: I suppose. I'd push back on those requirements: if there are supposed to be 2 files per directory then printing that there are 2 is not adding any useful information. It's only adding noise to the output. Here you can just to `if ! files_ok ; then echo problem;do_stuff;fi`